# React Native: Fetch api call is returning inappropriate response

Tags: javascript, json, react-native, fetch

I am making an api call to the server using fetch and the response json file is returning an undefined type of a response. I want to log the response and render it on the screen.

My source code for it:

```
'use strict';

import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View, Text, ListView, ScrollView} from 'react-native';

var ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});

class BusList extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
        this.state = {
            dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(['row 1', 'row 2']),
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.loadJSONData();
    }

    loadJSONData() {
        fetch('my_api!')
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json()
      })
      .then((responseJSON) => {
          return this.setState({dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(responseJSON)});
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.warn(error);
      });
}

renderRow(rowData) {
    return(
        <View>
            <Text>{rowData.data}</Text>
        </View>
    );
}

render() {
return (
  <View>
    <ListView
      dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
      renderRow={(rowData) => <Text>{rowData}</Text>}
    />
  </View>
);
  }
}

module.exports = BusList;
```

However, when I try logging it, I get the following [log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjbtd.png)

Please Help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think instead of making it to a json object without using any wrapper would make it pretty complex. You can do this:

```
//create state 
constructor() {
        super();
        const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
        this.state = {
            dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows([]),
            getData:[]
        };
    } 

 loadJSONData() {
        fetch('my_api!', {
            method: 'get',
            dataType: 'json',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
    })
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState({getData:response})
//putting response inside listview directly or you can put this.state.getData 
        this.setState({dataSource:ds.cloneWithRows(response)})
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.warn(error);
      });
```

Cheers :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works but the problem here is handling the json object!
Ok please give a brief description of handling the highly nested json object, or any link I could help me for the more appropriate implementation of rowHasChanged function, please!

Comment: whenever dataSource changes then it will re-render and your renderRow api of listView will fire to update the listview

Comment: In your renderRow() you will take a parameter renderRow(rowData) and after that you can simplify your json data using '.' operator, for example if you have some key name detail and inside that detail key there are more keys namely 'id' , 'address' etc, you can fetch 'address' of every row by rowData.detail.address. :)

Comment: Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {map}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check the render method of `Text`.

This is the log I am getting!